# Writing an infinitely running( while(true) { } ) user input function in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement a lexer in Haskell. For easy console input and output, I've used an intermediate data type **Transition Table**.

```
type TransitionTable = [(Int, Transitions String Int)]
type Transitions a b = [(a, b)]
```

I want to take input from the user for all the states and transitions. I do not want to take the total number of states before hand. I want it to keep taking input for the transitions of each state until the user types *"--"* . If the user types *"---"*, the current state is discarded and the input terminates.

After a lot of attempts I came up with this, which I think is horrible code.

```
-- |A function to emulate the while loop for easy IO functionality.
--  Defination:- while @comparator @func @start:
--      *comparator @arg: A function which returns True or False on the basis of @arg.
--          The loop stops when False is returned.
--      *func: The function which is executed repeadly.
--          It is responsible for returning the next @arg for the comparator on the basis of the current @arg.
--      *start: The starting value of @arg to pass to the comparator.
while :: (Monad m) => (a -> Bool) -> (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
while comparator func start =
    if comparator start then do
        nxt <- func start
        while comparator func nxt
    else
        return start

-- |A modification of putStr which flushes out stdout. Corrents buffer problems.
myPutStr :: String -> IO ()
myPutStr str = putStr str >> hFlush stdout >> return ()
```

---

```
-- Takes input from the console to generate a TransitionTable.
inputTransitionTable :: IO TransitionTable
inputTransitionTable = do
    putStrLn "Type -- for next state and --- for completing input entering."
    retVal <- while notFinished takeInfo (0, [])
    return (snd retVal)
        where
            -- Returns True when input entry is over.
            notFinished (i, _) = i > -1

            -- Takes the current state number and the incomplete corrosponding transition table which is populated 
            -- with user input. Input ends when user enters "---". State number is set to -1 when input is over.
            takeInfo (i, states) = do
                putStrLn ("Adding transitions to state " ++ show i ++ ": ")
                retVal <- while entryNotFinished takeStateInfo ("", [])
                let (inpStr, stateInfo) = retVal
                case inpStr == "---" of
                    True -> return (-1, states)
                    False -> return (i+1, states ++ [(i, stateInfo)])

            -- Checks if input entry is over. Returns False if finished.
            entryNotFinished (s, _)
                | s == "--" || s == "---"  =  False
                | otherwise  =  True

            -- Takes the input state number along with the corresponding transitions.
            -- Input ends when the user enters "--".
            takeStateInfo (str, state_info) = do
                myPutStr "\tEnter transitions symbol: "
                symbol <- getLine
                if symbol == "--" || symbol == "---" then
                    return (symbol, state_info)
                else do
                    myPutStr "\t\tEnter the transition state number: "
                    state' <- getLine
                    let state = read state' :: Int
                    return (str, (symbol, state):state_info)
```

Basically this is how it runs:

```
*Main> x <- inputTransitionTable
Type -- for next state and --- for completing input entering.
Adding transitions to state 0: 
    Enter transitions symbol: a
        Enter the transition state number: 1
    Enter transitions symbol: b
        Enter the transition state number: 2
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 1: 
    Enter transitions symbol: a
        Enter the transition state number: 2
    Enter transitions symbol: b
        Enter the transition state number: 3
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 2: 
    Enter transitions symbol: a
        Enter the transition state number: 3
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 3: 
    Enter transitions symbol: --
Adding transitions to state 4:
    Enter transitions symbol: ---
(0.03 secs, 344420 bytes)

-- Output
*Main> prettyPrintTransitionTable x
State   Transitions
0  ("b",2)  ("a",1)
1  ("b",3)  ("a",2)
2  ("a",3)
3
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Personally, I don't think [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-loops/0.3.3.0/doc/html/Control-Monad-Loops.html) is horrible at all. You've got some... less than idiomatic-code in `inputTransitionTable` but the loop portion seems fine to me, wheel-reinvention aside.

Comment: @C.A.McCann Oh, thanks. In my defense I'm still a beginner. The problem I have with the code is that it is extremely contorted and has too many nestings. I'm actually comparing it with code I wrote in C++, and while all pure bits of haskell are much more simpler and elegant than the C++ equivalent, here the haskell code looses badly.

Comment: Honestly, it's probably better than much of my beginner code was. The contortions are largely superficial and it could be tidied up easily--if it works, there's nothing fundamentally *wrong* with it. If you'd like the code de-contorted a bit, that's probably more appropriate for codereview.stackexchange.com than for SO. If you post it there, I'll give it a go tonight if nobody else does first.

Comment: Have a look at Parsec – nice tutorial available in Real World Haskel: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html

Comment: And just regarding the title: See the __forever__ function in the Control Monad: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Control-Monad.html#v%3Aforever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be as simple as this, if you add the "deriving Read" declarations and don't care about interaction.

```
main = do
    allInput <- getContents -- scarfs all stdin up to eof
    let inLines = lines allInput
    let (tableLines, _:otherlines) = break (== "endtable") inLines
    let table = ((read $ unlines tableLines) :: TransitionTable)
    -- process otherlines here
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, for a tasks related to parsing you should look at `Parsec`. While I have no experience with it, I can still suggest an alternative way of writing your parsing application.

```
module Main where

  import Control.Monad (liftM)

  computeTransitions :: [String] -> [(Int, [(String, Int)])]
  computeTransitions is = foldl folder [] is
    where
      getState states            = if null states then (0, []) else last states
      getTransition transitions  = if null transitions  then 0 else (snd $ head transitions)
      prepend state transition   = let (c, ts) = state in (c, transition:ts)
      swapLastState states state = if null states then [state] else init states ++ [state]
      folder states i =
        let currentState = getState states
            currentTransition = getTransition (snd currentState)
        in case i == "--" of False -> swapLastState states (prepend currentState (i, currentTransition + 1))
                             True  -> states ++ [((fst currentState) + 1, [])]

  main = do
    inputLines <- liftM (takeWhile (/="---")) (liftM lines getContents)
    let result = computeTransitions inputLines
    mapM_ (\(s, t) -> putStrLn $ show s ++ "\t" ++ show t) result
```

I don't know if in your requirements was to print out the intermediary messages, but the computation of the transitions can be transformed to a fold operation (or foldM if you want to print intermediary messages); and instead of the "while" loop I've used the `takeWhile` function lifted to the Monadic space (so I can apply it on the type `IO [String]`).

Also note that `getContents` is lazy in evaluation, and in combination with `lines` will perform as a "while read line".

**Edit:**

With @pat's suggestion (and what `hlint` came up with), here is the refactored version:

```
module Main where

  import Control.Monad (liftM)

  computeTransitions :: [String] -> [(Int, [(String, Int)])]
  computeTransitions = foldl folder []
    where
      getState []                = (0, [])
      getState states            = last states

      getTransition []           = 0
      getTransition ((_, t):_)  = t

      prepend (c,ts) transition  = (c, transition:ts)

      swapLastState [] state     = [state]
      swapLastState states state = init states ++ [state]

      folder states i =
        let currentState = getState states
            currentTransition = getTransition (snd currentState)
        in if i == "--"
          then states ++ [(fst currentState + 1, [])]
          else swapLastState states (prepend currentState (i, currentTransition + 1))

  main = do
    inputLines <- liftM (takeWhile (/="---") . lines) getContents
    mapM_ (\(s, t) -> putStrLn $ show s ++ "\t" ++ show t) (computeTransitions inputLines)
```

Comment: Pattern matching in the function arguments would eliminate all of the `if`s and the manual deconstruction (`fst`, `snd`, `head`).  Also `case` on a `bool` is just `if`.  You might also want to use function composition to eliminate the double `liftM`.